# How do you efficiently perform millions of t-tests in Python?

Tags: python, optimization, t-test

Long story short, I need to perform several hundred million t-tests. I have two lists of samples, `ys` and `ns`, and I want to compare a sample from each list, so the first sample in `ys` will be compared to the first sample in `ns` and so on. The result will be a list of p-values, one from each comparison. What is the fastest way to do this? Currently, I am using the `map` function

```
p_values = [result[1] for result in list(map(ttest_ind, ys, ns))]
```

but it is still slow. [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) looks like it might be faster, but I can't figure out how to use it with a function that takes two lists as input. Would it be faster if I hard coded the t-test math instead of using `scipy.stats.ttest_ind`?

Comment: `numpy.vectorize` just hides the mechanics of looping but doesn't really turn non-vectorized functions into genuinely vectorized functions. Have you looked into `pandas`?

Comment: How would I use `pandas`? Should I make `ys` and `ns` columns of a dataframe and apply the t-test to the columns instead?

Comment: I'm wincing at the "several hundred million" t-tests. Which is a topic for cross-validated...

Comment: @Michelle Yeah, it's hard to explain... Maybe I will try cross-validated instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole idea is: not running this in Python, but in C/C++.

For which you have two choices:

1. Write it in C/C++ yourself and connect it with Python.
2. Try to work with C/C++-backended libraries like Numpy. Pack your data as Numpy types and operate them with Numpy functions. In the backend it is running in C/C++, the same as 1, and it will be much easier.